# SQL: How do you find multiple records from an entire database, and then replace those records with 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, find, multiple-records

I hoping someone can help. Fairly new to SQL and in need of some advice.

Scenario:
I am trying to find multiple records (around 50 different records) throughout all tables in my database and then replace those with 1 value. The records that I will be looking for will be exact.

The solution I'm looking for ideally needs to be scalable as the number of records can increase.

Would anyone be able to help with this.

P.S. I have been using the below script but this only sets 1 variable at a time.

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON 

DECLARE @stringToFind VARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @stringToReplace VARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @schema sysname 
DECLARE @table sysname 
DECLARE @count INT 
DECLARE @sqlCommand VARCHAR(8000) 
DECLARE @where VARCHAR(8000) 
DECLARE @columnName sysname 
DECLARE @object_id INT 

SET @stringToFind = 'VALUE TO FIND'
SET @stringToReplace = 'VALUE TO REPLACE' 

DECLARE TAB_CURSOR CURSOR  FOR 
SELECT   B.NAME      AS SCHEMANAME, 
         A.NAME      AS TABLENAME, 
         A.OBJECT_ID 
FROM     sys.objects A 
         INNER JOIN sys.schemas B 
           ON A.SCHEMA_ID = B.SCHEMA_ID 
WHERE    TYPE = 'U' 
ORDER BY 1 

OPEN TAB_CURSOR 

FETCH NEXT FROM TAB_CURSOR 
INTO @schema, 
     @table, 
     @object_id 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE COL_CURSOR CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT A.NAME 
    FROM   sys.columns A 
           INNER JOIN sys.types B 
             ON A.SYSTEM_TYPE_ID = B.SYSTEM_TYPE_ID 
    WHERE  OBJECT_ID = @object_id 
           AND IS_COMPUTED = 0 
           AND B.NAME IN ('char','nchar','nvarchar','varchar','text','ntext') 

    OPEN COL_CURSOR 

    FETCH NEXT FROM COL_CURSOR 
    INTO @columnName 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
      BEGIN 
        SET @sqlCommand = 'UPDATE ' + @schema + '.' + @table + ' SET [' + @columnName 
                           + '] = REPLACE(convert(nvarchar(max),[' + @columnName + ']),''' 
                           + @stringToFind + ''',''' + @stringToReplace + ''')' 

        SET @where = ' WHERE [' + @columnName + '] LIKE ''%' + @stringToFind + '%''' 

        EXEC( @sqlCommand + @where) 

        SET @count = @@ROWCOUNT 

        IF @count > 0 
          BEGIN 
            PRINT @sqlCommand + @where 
            PRINT 'Updated: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@count) 
            PRINT '----------------------------------------------------' 
          END 

        FETCH NEXT FROM COL_CURSOR 
        INTO @columnName 
      END 

    CLOSE COL_CURSOR 
    DEALLOCATE COL_CURSOR 

    FETCH NEXT FROM TAB_CURSOR 
    INTO @schema, 
         @table, 
         @object_id 
  END 

CLOSE TAB_CURSOR 
DEALLOCATE TAB_CURSOR
```

Comment: What do you mean by replacing 50 records with one value? You mean deleting 49 of the records and updating the remaining record?

Comment: Sorry should have been more specific there: In my mind, I see this as more of a find and overwrite the existing value with the replacing value. Deleting the record wouldn't really be an option as there's too much referential integrity.

I'll just add. Maybe a mistake on my part for terminology but when I said record, I meant more or less a value that exists in any column throughout the database.

Comment: You want to do a global replace in all string columns in all tables?

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? `[]` around column names is SQL-Server syntax, MySQL uses backticks.

Comment: Sorry first time using this forum I added the wrong tag to the post. I am in fact using SQL SERVER. Very sorry.

Yeah basically a global replace based on an exact match.

Comment: Are you trying to create a repeatable process, hence the nested cursors and the dynamic SQL? If not, that's probably overcomplicated. While you're at it with the cursors, if your script "only sets 1 variable at a time", then add a third cursor and iterate over the set of variables. Personally, I would just write a straight-up update script and not rely on the complexity of this script.

Comment: I think you might be right, I'm probably overcomplicating it with the script that I have. The process does not have to be repeatable in that sense. 

I guess I'm just looking for a script that would take for e.g. ('abc_xyz','xyz_abc','abc','xyz') and replace with e.g. ('RANDOM WORD'). With the script that I have, I cannot SET multiple varibles.

As you said an update script might work... but not really sure how I would get that working. The nature of this is somewhat dynamic because I do not know the tables or columns that contain the values I stated above.